# Media Foundation SetInputType returns "The stream number provided was invalid"

Tags: windows, encoding, h.264, ms-media-foundation

I'm working on a H.264 encoder using the software H264 Encoder MFT available on my machine for the sake of simplicity (as opposed to the Intel QSV hardware encoder that I will be using eventually). Following a number of tutorials I've put together the following code:

```
IMFTransform* encoder;
DWORD numInputs, numOutputs;
DWORD *inputIDs, *outputIDs;
MFRatio fps = { 24, 1 }, par = { 1, 1 };
HRESULT hr;

hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    return hr;
}

// Create the MFT
hr = FindVideoEncoder(false, true, true, &encoder);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    return hr;
}

// Obtain number of streams attached to MFT
encoder->GetStreamCount(&numInputs, &numOutputs);

// Allocate appropriate size arrays
inputIDs = new DWORD[numInputs];
outputIDs = new DWORD[numOutputs];

// Obtain stream IDs
encoder->GetStreamIDs(numInputs, inputIDs, numOutputs, outputIDs);

// Set input and output types
IMFMediaType *inputType, *outputType;

CreateVideoType(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT, MFVideoInterlace_Unknown, fps, par,
    &outputType, MFMediaType_Video, MFVideoFormat_H264);
hr = encoder->SetOutputType(outputIDs[0], outputType, 0);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    return hr;
}

CreateVideoType(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT, MFVideoInterlace_Unknown, fps, par,
    &inputType, MFMediaType_Video, MFVideoFormat_Base);
hr = encoder->SetInputType(inputIDs[0], inputType, 0);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    return hr;
}
```

The code fails on the following line, giving a HRESULT value of "The stream number provided was invalid".

```
hr = encoder->SetOutputType(outputIDs[0], outputType, 0);
```

I tried to call SetInputType before SetOutputType however it yields the same error. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance for the answers.

EDIT: Added CreateVideoType function to show how the outputType and inputType is created

```
HRESULT CreateVideoType(
    UINT32               width,
    UINT32               height,
    MFVideoInterlaceMode interlaceMode,
    const MFRatio&       frameRate,
    const MFRatio&       par,
    IMFMediaType         **ppType,
    GUID                 majorType,
    GUID                 subtype
    )
{
    if (ppType == NULL)
    {
        return E_POINTER;
    }

    LONG    lStride = 0;
    UINT    cbImage = 0;

    IMFMediaType *pType = NULL;

    // Set the subtype GUID from the FOURCC or D3DFORMAT value.
    //subtype.Data1 = D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8;

    if (FAILED(MFCreateMediaType(&pType)))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    if (FAILED(pType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, majorType)))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    if (FAILED(pType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, subtype)))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    if (FAILED(pType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, interlaceMode)))
    {
        goto done;
    }


    if (FAILED(MFSetAttributeSize(pType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, width, height)))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Calculate the default stride value.
    if (FAILED(pType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE, UINT32(lStride))))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Calculate the image size in bytes.
    if (FAILED(MFCalculateImageSize(subtype, width, height, &cbImage)))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    if (FAILED(pType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE, cbImage)))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    if (FAILED(pType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES, TRUE)))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    if (FAILED(pType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, TRUE)))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Frame rate
    if (FAILED(MFSetAttributeRatio(pType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, frameRate.Numerator, frameRate.Denominator)))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Pixel aspect ratio   
    if (FAILED(MFSetAttributeRatio(pType, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, par.Numerator, par.Denominator)))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Return the pointer to the caller.
    *ppType = pType;
    (*ppType)->AddRef();

done:
    SafeRelease(&pType);
    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Hi, What result returns code `encoder->GetStreamIDs(numInputs, inputIDs, numOutputs, outputIDs);`? Microsoft H264 Encoder MFT works only with one stream. if method  `GetStreamIDs` return `E_NOTIMP` then it does not fill  `outputIDs` - check it.

Comment: The function returns one input and one output with the same ID; 3452816845. The HRESULT is indeed E_NOTIMPL.

Comment: It is wrong - same ID; 3452816845. ID MUST be 0 for both. It means that Microsoft H264 Encoder MFT  DOES NOT Implements `GetStreamIDs`.

Comment: When calling `hr = encoder->SetOutputType(0, outputType, 0);` i get an AccessViolation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFF. It seems that the ID is also a memory pointer to the stream.

Comment: How you create MediaType `outputType`? Are you sure that it points on correct memory?

Comment: I edited the question to add the output type creation function. It does not fail at any point and the pointer seems valid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138914/discussion-between-sincress-and-evgeny-pereguda).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft H264 Encoder MFT DOES NOT Implements `GetStreamIDs`- it returns E_NOTIMPL. You must set input and output stream ID to 0.

Answer (score 0):

As Evgeny pointed out in the discussion, there were several issues to be fixed before the code was working. Changing the `inputID` and `outputID` to 0 did the trick for the `SetInputType` and `SetOutputType` calls, however the creation of the video types had a few problems.

First the output type creation:

```
CreateH264VideoType(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT, MFVideoInterlace_Unknown, fps, par,
        &outputType, MFMediaType_Video, MFVideoFormat_H264);
```

In the function CreateH264VideoType I removed

```
 // Calculate the image size in bytes.

if (FAILED(MFCalculateImageSize(subtype, width, height, &cbImage)))
{
    goto done;
}
```

and I had to add

```
// Profile
if (FAILED(pType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_MPEG2_PROFILE, eAVEncH264VProfile_Base)))
{
    goto done;
}

// Bitrate
if (FAILED(pType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, 166723584)))
{
    goto done;
}
```

For the CreateUncompressedVideoType I removed MFCalculateImageSize and added the bitrate attribute set call. That resolved the errors with encoder initialization.